# Why I am getting wrong icon when using navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-icons

I am building application with navigation drawer. I want to add `ic_drawer` icon to it. I am using this for it:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
        R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
) { ... }

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Actually, I got wrong icon and also I don't have animation on it. How I can fix it? I can't rly find anything, except `drawable.ic_drawer` in my code.

Screens are below.

Blank screen screenshot.
  [image]

Opened menu screen.

[image]

You can see on both images, that it is not `ic_drawer` image. Actually, in IDEA, I see correct image.

Comment: If you are certain that the new image exist in your RES folder. Maybe try a  
Build>Clean Project ?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure You are using **v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle**

```
mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, your_drawer_layout, your_tool_bar, R.string.open, R.string.close
);
```

As you can see v7 ActionBarDraweToggle have different constructor and doesn't ask for your Icon. because it takes automatically from android resources.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need. I were using v4 action bar. Hm. I just added v7 action bar instead and I got blank screen with some text on it. I can see drawer icon in the top left corner, but there are no action bar and no toolbar, even if I am trying to open it. Do u know what can cause this problem?

Comment: Now are you stuck with color only ..then just refer this link https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html and read **Customize the Color Palette** and apply your color in style file like primaryColor and etc..

Answer (score 3):

You can refer [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) in Android Developer.

Few peoples skip this codes below. but the code is very important to show correct icon. 

I hope to you read more reference.

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

if you are using latest SDK, you may use compat-v7 and Toolbar.

I experienced burger icon isn't show. so I need other way.

finally solved using compt-v7 and Toolbar.

Comment: I found same advice on another website. Actually, I already have this code and icon still doesn't have animation. Also, I tried appcompat v7 drawer + toolbar, but stuck with adding mikepenz library for action bar. I can't add this lib as dependency to my project, so nav drawer is not working correctly (but animation of icon works :)). Do u know if there is some appcompat v7 + toolbar android example? Without libraries etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you add `DrawerLayout` listener with your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`? If not please add up these :

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);//mDrawerLayout is DrawerLayout
```

Comment: Ofc, I did this. I didn't mentioned all code in my question . I will update question about it.

Answer (score 0):

@Moinkhan is right. You need to replace your constructor from v4 to the new one from v7. Replace this old code:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    getActivity(),                    
    mDrawerLayout,                    
    R.drawable.ic_drawer,
    "Open drawer",  
    "Close drawer"
)
```

for this one

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

(remove old import from .v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle)

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    getActivity(), 
    mDrawerLayout, 
    "Open drawer", 
    "Close drawer"
);
```

It should now show an animated drawer icon that turns into left arrow when it is expanded